# Fit the size to the height of the screen

Tags: css, mobile, background, height, screen

it will surely be a trivial problem but I have been hitting my head for a long time.
The problem is simple, that is: I have an area with specific dimensions (450x800px) that I would like to always fit the height of the screen.

I am attaching here the sample code I am working on, thank you very much to those who can help me!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
html, body {  height: 100%;  margin: 0;}
.full-height {  height: 100%;  background: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="full-height">
    <div style="width:450px; height:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#FD0F13">I am a DIV that will stretch to fit the whole width and height of the browser window!</div>
</div>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Instead of `height: 100%;` change it to 100vh, which represents 100% of the viewport height

Comment: Thank you so much BeerusDev, maybe I'm wrong but nothing changes.
However, the goal should be that a 450x800px <div> space is scaled, enlarging or reducing it based on height.
Some idea? :(
Thank you